# How do I keep all data in a td side by side fixed height

Tags: php, html, css

I am trying to put all these three data side by side. Like the second row last column. but after the first column (within php loop) 3rd and 4th elements get to lower line.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPwsk.png)

here is what I have tried (included style in line.

```
<?php while ($each_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($table_data)){ ?>
                        <tr style="border: 1px solid black; ">
                            <td style="border: 1px solid black;"><?php echo $i; ?></td>
                            <td style="border: 1px solid black;"><?php echo $each_row["roll"]; ?></td>
                            <td style="border: 1px solid black;"><?php echo $each_row["name"]; ?></td>
                            <td style="border: 1px solid black; text-align:center;"><?php echo $each_row["present"]; ?></td>
                            <td style="border: 1px solid black; width: 300px;">
                                    <a href="attendence.php?change=present&date=<?php echo $today; ?>&class=<?php echo $class; ?>&batch=<?php echo $batch; ?>&roll=<?php echo $each_row["roll"]; ?>">
                                        <button type="button" name="button">Present</button></a>
                                    <a href="attendence.php?change=absent&date=<?php echo $today; ?>&class=<?php echo $class; ?>&batch=<?php echo $batch; ?>&roll=<?php echo $each_row["roll"]; ?>">
                                        <button type="button" name="button">Absent</button></a>
                                    <form class="" style="width: 100px;" action="attendence.php?change=absent&date=<?php echo $today; ?>&class=<?php echo $class; ?>&batch=<?php echo $batch; ?>&roll=<?php echo $each_row["roll"]; ?>" method="post">
                                        <input style="width: 50px;" type="text" name="late" value="0">
                                        <input style="width: 50px;" type="submit" name="" value="Late">
                                    </form>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
      <?php } ?>
```

Comment: well for one thing, `<form>` cannot be made child of `<table>`, to which those tags are unshown, but most likely outside your posted code.

Comment: Form cannot be child of <table> just like said before, and can we see your full CSS for this part please? I think you should consider using display:flex to achieve what you are trying to do.

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/24275151/
here is the whole table. I have used in line style will move it to style script later.

Comment: @Fred-ii `<form>` is a child of `<td>` here,  I guess this is legal HTML, right?

Comment: @Accountantم Nope; and there was a rather long discussion on the same issue yesterday regarding that.

Comment: I think its legal cause the code working just fine. I just need to keep them in line for look purpose that's all.

Comment: Then what do I do? any help changing the form or anything to make it work will be great. @Fred

Comment: Well, `<td>` doesn't have a content category and its allowed content is _flow content_, which `<form>` is.

Comment: @Shafi use your browser developer tools to see who is taking the space , or may be  your first `<form>` "display" property set to `inline-block`, while the rest of them `block`.  **check the elements with your browser developing tools**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a different view for your design, it might be little difficult for you to digest but you can go for BOOTSTRAP framework and use simple grid to design the same thing using `<div>` or `<span>` tags in the tabular view (which will be responsive too) and will make you form look even better. 

For Reference : [Bootstrap Grid System](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try the following structure. Consider using single `<form>` tag outside the main `<table>` and also consider *not* using the `<a>` anchor around the `<button>`.

```
<form method="post">
    <table style="width: 100%">
        <?php while ($each_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($table_data)){ ?>
        <tr style="border: 1px solid black;">
            <td style="border: 1px solid black;">1</td>
            <td style="border: 1px solid black;">2</td>
            <td style="border: 1px solid black;">3</td>
            <td style="border: 1px solid black; text-align:center;">4</td>
            <td style="border: 1px solid black; width: 300px;">
                <a href="#YourUrlHere"><!--CONSIDER REMOVING THIS ANCHOR-->
                    <button type="button" name="button">Present</button>
                </a><!--CONSIDER REMOVING THIS ANCHOR-->
                <a href="#YourUrlHere"><!--CONSIDER REMOVING THIS ANCHOR-->
                    <button type="button" name="button">Absent</button>
                </a><!--CONSIDER REMOVING THIS ANCHOR-->
                <input style="width: 50px;" type="text" name="late" value="0">
                <input style="width: 50px;" type="submit" name="" value="Late">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </table>
</form>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ksrgnmcm/#&togetherjs=Nl81IM2PG7

Hope it helps somehow.

Comment: It didn't solve the entire problem. But it did make things neat. Thanks and learnt a few new things. :D :D